# How to skip row when importing bad MySQL dump

Tags: bash, backup, mysql, mysql-error-1062

Given bad `mysqldump` that causes error on import:

```
namtar backups # mysql -p < 2010-12-01.sql
Enter password: 
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 8020: Duplicate entry 'l�he?' for key 'wrd_txt'
```

Is there an easy way to tell import to just skip given row and continue?

(Yes, I know I can manually edit the file or parse output, but it's not very convinient)

Comment: I was also having this issue I created a new database and then imported the data from .sql file into my newly created database. It worked for me.

Comment: In my case, triggers were causing duplicate entry error while import.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you can make the dump again you could add `--insert-ignore` to the command-line when dumping.

Or you can try using the **mysqlimport** command with `--force`,which will continue even if it encounters MySQL Errors.

Comment: I cannot create export again...and how do I use mysqlimport agains output from mysqldump --all-databases ?

Comment: I just tried using --force with mysql and it causes the insertion to stop when the error occurs.  mysqlimport doesn't work with an --all-databases dump, so that's out of the question as well.  The easiest way would be to edit the file, not to remove the offending line(s) which could be tedious, but to turn the "INSERT" commands into "INSERT IGNORE" commands.  A simple find/replace should suffice.  I realise it's not an ideal solution, but it's better than having to dig through the file replacing offending inserts manually when you find out about them.

Answer (score 45):

`mysql -f -p < 2010-12-01.sql`

the `-f` (force) being the operative option here, worked for me.

Comment: In my case, I restored .sql file in mysql cluster 5.5.29-7.2.10, -f also works. It lists all the ERROR lines, and this can also ignore the error like: ERROR 1528 (HY000) at line 22: Failed to create LOGFILE GROUP, and reuse the LOGFILE already created.

Answer (score 27):

Following the advice from jmlsteele's answer and comment, here's how to turn the inserts into `INSERT IGNORE` on the fly.

If you're importing from an `sql` file:

```
sed -e "s/^INSERT INTO/INSERT IGNORE INTO/" < 2010-12-01.sql | mysql -p
```

If you're importing from a `gz` file, just pipe the output from gunzip into sed instead of using the file input:

```
gunzip < 2010-12-01.sql.gz | sed -e "s/^INSERT INTO/INSERT IGNORE INTO/" | mysql -p
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also replace "INSERT INTO" texts inside text fields?

Comment: @Almad - It would only change the first INSERT INTO, and any additional on the same line would not be changed.  As far as I'm aware, any time you'd have "INSERT INTO" in a text field it would be following an INSERT INTO statement -- But, I changed the answer to make sure its only replaced when its at the beginning of a new line.

Comment: A dump can have multiple INSERT statements (even thousands or more) per-row: in that case the solution wouldn't affect the other statements after the first. Maybe with a more complex regex it's possible to achieve the result, substituting only the INSERT INTO not in text fields.

Comment: It COULD have multiple statements per row, but only if produced by hand. Which limits effective size of the file and amount of data stored. In most common use case, the dump is provided by `mysqldump` or similar utilities and contains one insert statement per line at most.

Answer (score 4):

Great tip. I did it a little different but same result.

```
perl -pi -e 's/INSERT INTO/INSERT IGNORE INTO/g' filename.sql
```

Comment: do you mind explain your code

Answer (score 3):

The other options certainly are viable options, but another solution would be to simply edit the `.sql` file obtained from the `mysqldump`.

Change:

```
INSERT INTO table_name ...
```

TO

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name ...
```

Comment: @Almad the solution you linked allows you to make the same change I proposed from the command line at the time of importing and does not modify the .sql file.  My suggestion here is to actually open the file, edit its contents and save the file before importing.  While similar I don't feel these are duplicate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought did you delete the MySQL directives at the top of dump? 
(I unintentionally did when I restarted a restore after deleting all the records/tables I'd already inserted with a sed command). These directives tell MySQL ,among other things, not to do unique tests, foreign key tests etc)

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```