# ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 3907: Duplicate entry '1985' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql

After trying to import my database.sql, I received this error.

ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 3907: Duplicate entry '1985' for key 'PRIMARY'

I've tried to read here but I really don't understand them. Is there a solution that I can use to import my database properly?

Thanks,

Comment: You have 2 entries with primary key 1985. maybe you want to drop all other records before importing?

Comment: Duplicate entry for primary key

Comment: I already dropped the database, but still receiving the same error. I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same Primary Key in your import file. Go to that line and remove that line or the second possibility is that you set the flag to ignore the IDs but then you have inconsistent data and a dublicate primary key.

[How to skip row when importing bad MySQL dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622253/how-to-skip-row-when-importing-bad-mysql-dump)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug. Just change INSERT INTO to REPLACE INTO in self-contained file.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Primary-key,we can't insert duplicate data,so before import database sql files,we must clear the database or tables;