# Is there a generic way to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a db dump and its so huge(nearly 150gb). I want to insert this dump data to another schema which also has data. There are some identical rows and they gives Duplicate entry error when I try to import this dump. Is there a way to "insert if not exists while importing this dump"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to skip row when importing bad MySQL dump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622253/how-to-skip-row-when-importing-bad-mysql-dump)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485674/how-to-skip-duplicate-records-when-importing-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `insert on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into table1(id, col1, . . .)
     select id, col1, col2, . . 
     from table2
     on duplicate key update id = values(id);
```

For this to work, you need a unique index (or constraint) on the id column(s).  Duplicates in this column are not allowed.

The `on duplicate key` part says to update the record when a duplicate is found.  The `id = values(id)` is a no-op.  The id is set to itself, so it does nothing and the effect of the statement is just to insert rows that are not in the original table.

Comment: The user also may prefer renouncing to update as the original question possibly suggest by "if not exists".

Answer (score 0):

Well if I get you right - yes.

You can use `EXCEPT` in the `INSERT` commands.

See this example:

```
INSERT INTO yourTargetTable(name)
    SELECT name
    FROM yourSourceTable
    EXCEPT
    SELECT name
    FROM yourTargetTable
```