# How to execute SQL queries skipping error?

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to import to table data from sql files using command line.
This data contents duplicates in filed `url`.

But field `url` in table is unique. So when I try to insert data I get error "Dublicate entry"

How to inmport all data skipping this error?

Comment: You should probably import to a new table, and insert only unique records.

Comment: Show the code that you are using to bring the data in.

Comment: How to do this? Create one table and how insert only unique rows?

Comment: look at this post
http://stackoverflow.com/a/812462/3956479

Comment: You should create query from the table you have created with DISTINCT Or GROUP BY if is possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip row when importing bad MySQL dump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622253/how-to-skip-row-when-importing-bad-mysql-dump)

Comment: When `url` is a duplicate, Is the whole row is a duplicate? how do you want to choose between duplicate rows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can to use the --force (-f) flag.

```
mysql -u userName -p -f -D dbName < script.sql
```

From `man mysql`:

> ·   --force, -f
>
> Continue even if an SQL error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

- Create a staging table with the same structure as your destination
  table but without the constraints (unique index included).
- Manually check the duplicates and decide on the way you want to
  choose between duplicates rows / merge rows.
- Write the appropriate query and use "insert into ... select ...".

Answer (score 0):

> How to inmport all data skipping this error?

Drop the index for time being -> run your batch insert -> recreate the index back

Comment: `recreate the index back` will be failed

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `insert`, the you can ignore errors using `ignore error` or `on duplicate key update` (preferable because it only ignores duplicate key errors).

If you are using `load data infile`, then you can use the `ignore` key word.  As described in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html):

> If you specify `IGNORE`, rows that duplicate an existing row on a
>   unique key value are discarded. For more information, see Comparison
>   of the IGNORE Keyword and Strict SQL Mode.

Or, do as I would normally do:

- Load the data into a staging table.
- Validate the staging table and only load the appropriate data into the final table.